# http content type, and binary data

Tags: http, binary, content-type

I thought I knew this already but now I'm not sure: Is all content sent over http always encoded to character data? ie, if my content type is a binary file type, is it always converted to binhex, or is it possible to send "actual" binary data across the wire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTTP there is no content transfer encoding (e.g. base64) done, so binary data is sent just binary, byte-by-byte.

Answer (score 2):

Character data is just binary data with special meaning to humans :p
The actual body of the HTTP request may be encoded and/or compressed, and this is specified in the headers.

Comment: Yes. according to the request the response may be gzipped if the request has accept gzip header